# package ‘titletoc’ in R

Tags: r, latex

I got the error message: "package ‘titletoc’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)" but I checked MiKTeX Console that the package "titlesec" is in the list of packages and all the packages are updates. I am using a Mac (not sure if it matters). 
Then I searched online to try to install the package "titletoc" separately, but I found nowhere to download this package. Something must be wrong, anyone has a clue?

Comment: `titletoc` seems to be a LaTeX package, not an R package. What exactly were you running when you got that error? Normally that error comes from using `install.packages()` but that's not you install R packages, not LaTeX packages. If it's in your MiKTeX console then it's probably already installed. So why are you trying to install it again? Is there some other you are trying to fix?

Comment: Edit your question to include the error message. Copy/pasting the text is better than a screenshot because the text in a screen shot isn't searchable.

Comment: See this:    tlmgr search --file --global '/titletoc.sty'.        tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! LaTeX Error: File `titletoc.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
Error: Failed to compile ../../Reports/draft.tex. 
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("tlmgr", args, ...) :
  running command ''tlmgr' search --file --global '/titletoc.sty'' had status 1

Comment: I think now the question turns out to be: how to add a package to LaTex?

Comment: Can you clarify if you use miktex or texlive? Your question talks about miktex, but the commands you mention in comments are from texlive

Comment: I installed both MiKTeX and MacTex. Now I removed MiKTeX and reinstalled MacTex.